# Why does the frequency reduce if I use ifelse function in R?Is there a way to create categories from the combination of 2 variables/columns?

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

when I do

```
table(df$strategy.x)
0  1    2     3
70 514  223  209

table(df$strategy.y)
  0   1   2   3 
729  24   7   4
```

I want to create a variable with both of these combined. I tried this

```
df <- df %>%
      mutate(nstrategy1 = ifelse(strategy.x==1| strategy.y==1 , 1, 0))
table(df$nstrategy1)

  0   1 
399 519
```

I am supposed to get 514 + 24 = 538 but I got 519 instead

```
df <- df %>% mutate(nstrategy2 = ifelse(strategy.x==2| strategy.y==2 , 1, 0))
table(df$nstrategy2)

  0   1 
578 228
```

Similarly, I am supposed to get 223 + 7 = 230, but I got 228 instead

Is there a good way to merge both strategy.x and strategy.y and end up with a table like the following with 4 categories?

```
0    1    2     3
799  538  230  213
```

Comment: I'd guess they're not disjoint sets, i.e. some cases where y == 2 are already accounted for in y == 1.

Comment: I suppose df is a dataframe. therefore columns strategy.x and strategy.y should have the same length. Since the total for `table(strategy.x)` is 1016 and the total of `table(strategy.y)` is 764, I understand you have many NAs in each column. The reason why you don't have the expected value is because you must have some rows where strategy.x and strrategy.y have the same value. use this: `table(df$strategy.x, df$strategy.x, useNA="always")` to have a better picture of what you're looking at.

Comment: anyhow... your question is not well-defined. it is not really clear what your goal is. Also, when you post a question on SO, you usually want to share a reproducible example and some [not necessarily all] of your data. The data provided should be enough to show the issue you're dealing with and allow other people to reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
table(mtcars$am)  # 13 1's
table(mtcars$vs)  # 14 1's

mtcars$ones = ifelse(mtcars$am == 1 | mtcars$vs == 1, 1, 0)

table(mtcars$ones) # 20 1's   <  13 + 14 = 27
```

Why is it showing only 20 1's instead of 27? It's because there are 7 + 6 + 7 = 20 cars with either one or two 1's in am and vs. There are 13 with am==1 (6+7), and 14 with vs==1 (7+7). Seven cars are in the bottom left because they have 1's in both dimensions, which you are expecting/seeking to count twice.

```
table(mtcars$am, mtcars$vs)
#     0  1
#  0 12  7
#  1  6  7
```

The simplest way to get the sum of the two results would be by adding the two table objects:

```
table(mtcars$am) + table(mtcars$vs)  
 #  0  1 
 # 37 27
```